# Neo4 modeling: using relationship properties to navigate graph - antipattern alternatives

Tags: neo4j

I am working on an application that will allow users to recommend learning paths based on available online courses:

[image]

In my current model, Sequences are distinct nodes. They mark the start of a user-created learning path, and contain other useful metadata about the sequence (ex: the field of knowledge, user ratings, etc.)

We then use the NEXT relationships to navigate through all the courses that the user-defined sequence might contain.

A single course may be part of many different user-created Sequences, so there may be an arbitrary number of NEXT relationships between two course nodes, and each relationship will have the id of the parent Sequence as a property.

This means that when fetching a Sequence, the dbms will need to follow the NEXT relationships matching a particular path_id in order to retrieve all the course nodes associated with that course.

I've read from different sources that using relationship properties to navigate a graph is an antipattern, because it causes I/O accesses over the number of relationships.

I'd only expect sequences to be around 20-30 courses long max. On the other hand, I expect that fetching entire sequences will be a very frequent operation in the app.

My question is: is the antipattern reasonable here, or are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new nodes (labelled, say, `CourseRef`) that reference the `Course` nodes, with the `CourseRef` nodes chained together by `NEXT` relationships (that don't store sequence ids). Each `Sequence` node would have a reference to the first `CourseRef` in a chain. The `Course` nodes themselves would then not need to be chained together any more.

This could be the new data model:

```
(:User)-[:SUBSCRIBED_TO]->(:Sequence)
(:Sequence)-[:STARTS_AT]->(:CourseRef)
(:Course)<-[:REFERS_TO]-(:CourseRef)-[:NEXT]->(:CourseRef)
(:Course)-[:REQUIRED_BY]->(:Course)
```

With the above data model, you can get all the `Course` paths (there can be more than one, as in your example) for each `Sequence` of a `User` this way:

```
MATCH (u:User {id: 123})-[:SUBSCRIBED_TO]->(seq)-[:STARTS_AT]->(r1)
MATCH path = (r1)-[:NEXT*0..]->(r2)
WHERE SIZE((r2)-[:NEXT]->()) = 0
UNWIND NODES(path) AS ref
MATCH (ref)-[:REFERS_TO]-(course)
RETURN u, seq.id AS seqId, COLLECT(course) AS courses
```

The `WHERE` clause does a quick degreeness check on `r2` to make sure that it is the leaf `Course` in a path.

Comment: This might actually be a really good solution. My model also requires some data so that sequence creators may add their own input about a given course (for example, comments, difficulty ratings, etc). This kills two birds with one stone. Thanks!